# Re-creating file extentions for easy loading in R

Tags: r

I am trying to read in a number of datasets (approx 300) all with similar names to the following (I am not loading them all in at the same time, but I am trying to find a generalised solution where I only change a few things at the beginning of the R file)

```
E:/Data/Academic/Year1/External/beer/beer_drug_1114_1165
E:/Data/Academic/Year1/External/beer/beer_groc_1114_1165

E:/Data/Academic/Year1/External/beer/beer_PANEL_DR_1114_1165.dat
E:/Data/Academic/Year1/External/beer/beer_PANEL_GR_1114_1165.dat
E:/Data/Academic/Year1/External/beer/beer_PANEL_MA_1114_1165
E:/Data/Academic/Year1/External/beer/Delivery_Stores
```

The only things which changes are;

`Year1` in the `E:/Data/Academic/Year1/External`

`beer` in the `beer/beer_drug_1114_1165`

`1114_1165` at the end and the extentions

So I am trying different combinations of `paste0` in order to recreate the file extentions.

I have something such as the following which isn´t working so well.

```
file <- "E:/IRI Data/Academic Dataset External/Year1/External/"
product <- "/beer"
weeks <- "_1114_1165"

paste0(file, product, product, weeks)
```

But I would like to change /Year1/ in the middle of the extension.

Extentions:

```
drug <- read.table("E:/Data/Academic/Year1/External/beer/beer_drug_1114_1165", header = TRUE)
groc <- read.table("E:/Data/Academic/Year1/External/beer/beer_groc_1114_1165", header = TRUE)


PANEL_DR <- read.delim("E:/Data/Academic/Year1/External/beer/beer_PANEL_DR_1114_1165.dat", header = TRUE)
PANEL_GR <- read.delim("E:/Data/Academic/Year1/External/beer/beer_PANEL_GR_1114_1165.dat", header = TRUE)
PANEL_MA <- read.delim("E:/Data/Academic/Year1/External/beer/beer_PANEL_MA_1114_1165.dat", header = TRUE)


Delivery_Stores <- read.fwf("E:/Data/Academic/Year1/External/beer/Delivery_Stores",
                            widths = c(7, 3, 9, 21, 5, 4, 5, 9))
```

Comment: you can use `gsub` to replace "/Year1" with what ever other option you would like.  `gsub("Year1", "Year23", "E:/IRI Data/Academic Dataset External/Year1/External")` assuming there aren't any other `Year1` in the path string

Comment: Thats a good idea!

Comment: also I suggest using `file.path()` when generating directory paths, and read the [`here` package](https://github.com/jennybc/here_here) on best practices on working directories. As for the terminal `weeks` string, if they follow a consistent pattern (same length of digits with the "_") then you can use regular expression identify and replace the terminal end of the file paths